# Component does not receive mouse event anymore after it has been re-added in parent component in Java 8

Tags: java, mouseevent, components, repaint

Basically I have a Task class extends JComponent, each task could overlap each other. When I mouse press one task, it can be brought to front if it is overlapped by other tasks. Then I can drag and drop the task to somewhere else. It worked fine in Java 7, but failed in Java 8. All the followup events like mouse dragged and mouse released after mouse pressed will not be fired in Java 8.

```
// Task.java

public class Task extends JComponent{
    String _text;
    public Task(String text){
        _text = text;
        new TaskListener(this);
    }
}


// TaskListener.java

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class TaskListener extends MouseInputAdapter {

    private Task _task;

    public TaskListener(Task task){
        _task = task;
        _task.addMouseListener(this);
        _task.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }  

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse dragged");
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse clicked");
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse entered");
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse exited");
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse moved");
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse pressed");
        // to get task to front in case it is overlapped by other tasks
        // which will prevent follow up events from firing out in Java 8
        Container parent = _task.getParent();
        parent.remove(_task);
        parent.add(_task, 0);
        _task.repaint(); 
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse released");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

instead of re-add task, I use parent.setComponentZOrder(_task, 0) 
to change the task's z-order to make it back to front.